# How to store different character's positon using vector or map

Tags: c++

I have a string like "aabcdba" now I want to store the position of different character's position. I am trying to store using `vector` and `unordered_map`. Is there any good approach to store the position of different characters?

```
void topKFrequent(string s) {
    vector<vector<int> >v(123);
    //unordered_map<char, vector<int>>m;
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++) {
        v[s[i]].push_back(i);
       // m[s[i]].push_back(i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<123;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<v[i].size();j++) {
               char ch=i;
               cout<<ch<<"->"<<v[i][j]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

if string = "aabcdba", I want the following result:

```
 a->0,1,6;
 b->2,5;
 c->3;
 d->4;
```

Comment: Why do you need to store these positions?  What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: Belaying for a brief moment the why behind this cause, since the code you posted invokes *undefined behavior* using your vector of vectors approach, I'd go with *not* doing it that way.

Comment: i am trying to solve a problem and the problem is :"Given a non-empty string str and an integer k, rearrange the string such that the same characters are at least distance k from each other."

Comment: yes @WhozCraig the code does not run and i want to know the proper implementation and if there are any other way to store because if i use 2d vector then i have to indexing 1 to 123 but i just want to map char to it's position.

Comment: Now above code runs fine but i can not implement using unordered_map.@WhozCraig

Comment: Out of curisoity, is [**this**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-a-string-so-that-all-same-characters-become-at-least-d-distance-away/) the problem you're trying to solve? If so, you may find the letter *frequencies*, not original positions, are important. Regardless, an unordered map of `char` to vector of `unsigned int` will do what *you're* asking for. If you simply need to know the *count* of each char in a string, (to determine each char's frequency) an unordered map of `char` to `unsigned int` would do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `map<char, vector<unsigned int> >`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

map<char, vector<unsigned int> > storePos(string s)
{
    map<char, vector<unsigned int> > charPos;
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    {
        auto itr = charPos.find(s[i]);
        if(itr != charPos.end())
        {
            itr->second.push_back(i);
        }
        else
        {
            charPos[s[i]] = vector<unsigned int>(1, i);
        }
    }
    return charPos;
}

int main(void)
{
    string example = "aabcdba";

    auto result = storePos(example);

    for(auto itr1 = result.begin(); itr1 != result.end(); itr1 ++)
    {
        cout << "Letter: " << itr1->first << ", Locations: ";
        for(auto itr2 = itr1->second.begin(); itr2 != itr1->second.end();
            itr2 ++)
        {
            cout << *itr2 << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to store ordinal positions in the original string sequence, you can do so with either an unordered or ordered map of `char` to `vector`, where `char` is the key, and the `vector` contains the positions. Using an unordered map will *not* give you the lexicographical ordering of keys you seem to be seeking, but will nonetheless give you accurate positional vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "aabcdba";
    std::unordered_map<char, std::vector<unsigned int>> mymap;

    for (unsigned i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
        mymap[s[i]].push_back(i);

    for (auto const& pr : mymap)
    {
        std::cout << pr.first << "->";
        auto it = pr.second.cbegin();
        std::cout << *it;
        while (++it != pr.second.cend())
            std::cout << ',' << *it;
        std::cout << ";\n";
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
d->4;
c->3;
b->2,5;
a->0,1,6;
```

If you want lexicographical ordering, the simplest alternative is to simply using a regular ordered map instead. Changing only this:

```
std::unordered_map<char, std::vector<unsigned int>> mymap;
```

to this:

```
std::map<char, std::vector<unsigned int>> mymap;
```

and including the appropriate header delivers us this for output:

```
a->0,1,6;
b->2,5;
c->3;
d->4;
```

which fits *exactly* what you seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A possible implementation to store the positions could be using unordered_multimap: (where the key characters can be repeated).

```
void storePos(string s) {
    unordered_multimap<char, int>m;
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++) {
        m.insert(make_pair(s[i],i));
    }
}
```

[EDITED]
But the output may depend on how you use it, or print out the data.

For example, consider the use of a `std::multimap` instead of `std::unordered_map`, to populate it you just do:

```
multimap<char, int>m;

void storePos(string s) {
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++) {
        m.insert(make_pair(s[i],i));
    }
}
```

And to print the data you could have the following method:

```
void printPos() 
{
    std::multimap<char,int>::iterator it,itup;

    for (it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); )
    {
       cout << (*it).first << " -> ";
       itup = m.upper_bound ((*it).first );
      // print range [it,itup):
      for (it; it!=itup; ++it)
      {
        cout << (*it).second << ", ";
      }
      cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a -> 0, 1, 6, 
b -> 2, 5, 
c -> 3, 
d -> 4,
```

[Try this!](http://ideone.com/nLr77m)

Comment: if string = "aabb",your output:a->0;a->1;b->2;b->3;but i need:a->0,1;b->2,3